# How to use pykinect to fuse depth map and color map

Tags: python, opencv, kinect, pykinect

I have now completed the calibration of Kinect depth camera and RGB camera, obtained the internal and external parameters, FX, FY, CX and cy of the camera with MATLAB, and calculated R and T with the external parameters. The next step I need to do is to use pykinect and python 3 to complete the integration of Kinect depth map and color map, but I have not found a solution now.